# How can I create all possible combinations for a set of words without repetition?

Tags: c#, string, combinations

I have 10 words. How can I get all possible combinations of 5 words `(n=10, k=5)`. The order **does not matter**.

For example: "A", "B", "C", with k=2 and n=3 should result in "AB", "BC" and "AC".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What you are trying to do is get all the permutations of a collection.

- [Unique permutations of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249051/unique-permutations-of-list)
- [permutations of k objects from a set of n algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180970/permutations-of-k-objects-from-a-set-of-n-algorithm)

Here is the code snippet:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    var result = GetPermutations(list, 3);
    foreach (var perm in result)
    {
        foreach (var c in perm)
        {
            Console.Write(c + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPermutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (count == 1)
            yield return new T[] { item };
        else
        {
            foreach (var result in GetPermutations(items.Skip(i + 1), count - 1))
                yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
a b c 
a b d 
a b e 
a c d 
a c e 
a d e 
b c d 
b c e 
b d e 
c d e
```

Comment: To be more mathematically correct. You call this combinations (order is not important) without repetition (an item may occur at most 1 time or less). https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: Doesn't "at most 1 time" imply "or less"?

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I put together:

```
static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CombinationsWithoutRepetition<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> items,
        int ofLength)
    {
        return (ofLength == 1) ?
            items.Select(item => new[] { item }) :
            items.SelectMany((item, i) => items.Skip(i + 1)
                                               .CombinationsWithoutRepetition(ofLength - 1)
                                               .Select(result => new T[] { item }.Concat(result)));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CombinationsWithoutRepetition<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> items,
        int ofLength,
        int upToLength)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(ofLength, Math.Max(0, upToLength - ofLength + 1))
                         .SelectMany(len => items.CombinationsWithoutRepetition(ofLength: len));
    }

}
```

...

```
foreach (var c in new[] {"a","b","c","d"}.CombinationsWithoutRepetition(ofLength: 2, upToLength: 4))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', c));
}
```

produces:

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d
a,b,c
a,b,d
a,c,d
b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```

Note that this is concise but inefficient and should not be used for large sets or inner loops.  Notably, the short arrays are re-created multiple times and could be memoized, and the `IEnumerable` will be iterated multiple times, which can cause unexpected work if care is not taken.

Also, if the input contains duplicates then the output will as well.  Either use `.Distinct().ToArray()` first, or use another solution which includes equality checking and, presumably, takes an `IEqualityComparer` for generality.

Answer (score 1):

```
public IActionResult Index() 
{
    var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
    List<string> ret = GetAllCombinations(list).OrderBy(_ => _).ToList();

    return View();
}

static IEnumerable<string> GetAllCombinations(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    return list.SelectMany((mainItem, mi) => list.Where((otherItem, oi) => mi < oi)
                              .Select(otherItem => mainItem + otherItem));
}
```

Ouput ret:

```
ab
ac
ad
ae
bc
bd
be
cd
ce
de
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What about a more functional solution

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
GetAllCombinations(list).OrderBy(_ => _).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);


static IEnumerable<string> GetAllCombinations(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    return list.SelectMany(mainItem => list.Where(otherItem => !otherItem.Equals(mainItem))
                              .Select(otherItem => mainItem + otherItem));
}
```

Ouput:

```
ab
ac
ad
ae
ba
bc
bd
be
ca
cb
cd
ce
da
db
dc
de
ea
eb
ec
ed
```

Comment: The OP specified that the order does not matter, so "ab" and "ba", which both appear in the result of that code, are the same.