# Invalid cast from IEnumerable to List

Tags: c#, casting, type-conversion

I'm working on a C# script within a Unity3D Project where I'm trying to take a list of strings and get a 2D list of the permutations. Using [this answer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12249225/5812876) `GetPermutations()` in the following fashion:

```
List<string> ingredientList = new List<string>(new string[] { "ingredient1", "ingredient2", "ingredient3" });

List<List<string>> permutationLists = GetPermutations(ingredientList, ingredientList.Count);
```

But it throws an implicit conversion error:

`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> to List<List<string>> ... An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)?`

So I looked at a few places, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617771/converting-from-ienumerable-to-list) and came up with the following modification:

```
List<List<string>> permutationLists = GetPermutations(ingredientList, ingredientList.Count).Cast<List<string>>().ToList();
```

But it breaks at runtime, gets handled internally, and allows it to continue without indicating a failure – probably because it's running in Unity3D.
Here is what I see in Unity3D after I stop debugging the script:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
System.Linq.Enumerable+<CreateCastIterator>c__Iterator0`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]].MoveNext ()
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:128)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:65)
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[List`1] (IEnumerable`1 source)
```

Which I interpret as still casting incorrectly, so I also attempted the following approaches and more that I can't remember:

```
List<List<string>> permutationLists = GetPermutations(ingredientList, ingredientList.Count).Cast<List<List<string>>>();

List<List<string>> permutationLists = GetPermutations(ingredientList.AsEnumerable(), ingredientList.Count);
```

as well as explicitly casting with parenthesis before the method call like you would in C or Java, still to no avail.

---

So how should I be casting the results from the `GetPermutations()` function to get a `List<List<string>>`? Or alternatively, how could I modify the function to only return `List<List<string>>` since I don't need it to work for a generic type? I tried to modify the method myself to be the following:

```
List<List<string>> GetPermutations(List<string> items, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if(count == 1)
            yield return new string[] { item };
        else
        {
            foreach(var result in GetPermutations(items.Skip(i + 1), count - 1))
                yield return new string[] { item }.Concat(result);
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```

However, having removed the `<T>` from the function name it breaks stating that the body cannot be an iterator block. I have no prior experience with C# and I'm rusty with template functions in strongly typed languages, so any explanation/help is appreciated.

I wasn't sure how to look this issue up, so if this is a duplicate just post it here and I'll delete this post immediately.

Comment: You need something like `GetPermutations(...).Select(c => c.ToList()).ToList()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So how should I be casting the results from the GetPermutations() function to get a `List<List<string>>`

Best solution: don't.  Why do you need to turn the sequence into a list in the first place? Keep it as a sequence of sequences.

If you must though:

```
GetPermutations(...).Select(s => s.ToList()).ToList()
```

If you want to modify the original method, just do the same thing:

```
IEnumerable<List<string>> GetPermutations(List<string> items, int count)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if(count == 1)
            yield return new List<T>() { item };
        else
        {
            foreach(var result in GetPermutations(items.Skip(i + 1), count - 1))
                yield return (new string[] {item}.Concat(result)).ToList();
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```

And then do `GetPermutations(whatever).ToList()` and you have a list of lists. But again, do not do this.  Keep everything in sequences if you possibly can.

> I want to turn the sequence into a list so that I can sort the elements alphabetically and re-join them as a sorted, single comma-delimited string.

OK, then do that.  Let's rewrite your method as an extension method `Permute()`. And let's make some new one-liner methods:

```
static public string CommaSeparate(this IEnumerable<string> items) =>
  string.Join(",", items);

static public string WithNewLines(this IEnumerable<string> items) =>
  string.Join("\n", items);

static public IEnumerable<string> StringSort(this IEnumerable<string> items) =>
  items.OrderBy(s => s);
```

Then we have the following -- I'll annotate the types as we go:

```
string result = 
  ingredients                    // List<string>
  .Permute()                     // IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
  .Select(p => p.StringSort())   // IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>
  .Select(p => p.CommaSeparate())// IEnumerable<string>
  .WithNewLines();                   // string
```

And we're done.  **Look at how clear and straightforward the code is when you make methods that do one thing and do it well**. And look at how easy it is when you keep everything in sequences, as it should be.

Comment: I want to turn the sequence into a list so that I can sort the elements alphabetically and re-join them as a sorted, single comma-delimited string. I began with a list because I was familiar with it, but I will look into using the return value since you say it's possible to use it as-is.

Comment: @DarrelHolt You can sort a sequence just as easily as you can sort a list, and you can join sequences just as easily as you can join lists.

Comment: @DarrelHolt: Servy is almost correct. It is *easier* to do the work in sequences than in lists because *you never have to worry that someone mutated the sequence on you*.

Comment: @Servy I don't see a built-in sort function for `IEnumerable`, but I do for `List`, what is the sorting method name for sequences?

Comment: @DarrelHolt: `OrderBy`.  **You would do well to read up on the standard sequence operators if you are going to be programming using sequences**.

Comment: @DarrelHolt: I've updated the answer to show how to solve your larger problem.  **Use fluent style to make you program both easy to read and obviously correct**.

Comment: @EricLippert so fluent style is chaining the commands so that it seems "Fluent" as if you were reading a sequence of events? I have only seen this concept used in JS, thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: @DarrelHolt: That's correct. We think of operations on sequences as a workflow of chained operations where each sequence flows values into the next operation.  If the subject of producing permutations in C# interests you, I've written many articles on clever ways to do so.

Comment: @EricLippert Awesome, I'll take a look at some of your posts. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is related to several aspects of C# and .net types system. I will try to provide simple explanation and will provide links as more formal answers.

So, according to your description it looks like `GetPermutations(ingredientList, ingredientList.Count);` returns `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`  but you are trying to assign this result to the variable of another type, in pseudo code:

```
List<List<string>> = IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>;
```

`List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`,  so in general it is possible to make this assignment:

```
IEnumerable<T> = List<T>;
```

but the problem is that in your case `T` on the left side differs from the `T` on the right side.

- for `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` `T` is `IEnumerable<string>`.
- for `List<List<string>>` `T` is `List<string>`

To fix your problem we should change the code to have the same `T` on the left and right sides i.e. convert `T` to either `List<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>`.

You can convert `T` to the `List<string>` this way:

```
IEnumerable<List<string> GetPermutationsList(List<string> items, int count)
{
    return GetPermutations(items, count).Select(x=>x.ToList())
}
IEnumerable<List<string>> permutationLists = GetPermutations(ingredientList.AsEnumerable(), ingredientList.Count);
// or
List<List<string>> permutationLists = GetPermutations(ingredientList.AsEnumerable(), ingredientList.Count).ToList();
```

but in general it is not good idea to use List in all places. Use lists only where you really need it. Important points here:

- `IEnumerable<T>` provides minimum functionality (enumeration only) that should be enougth for your goals.
- `IList <T>` (List implements it ) provides maximum functionality (Add, Remove ,“random” access by index). Do you really need maximum functionality?
- Also using `ToList()` can cause memory shortage problem for big data.
- `ToList()`  just forces immediate query evaluation and returns a `List<T>`

Some useful information: [covariance-contr-variance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), [casting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions)