# How do I create groups of combinations that match specific conditions in C#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, combinations

I have a list of people `List<Person>` who I need to produce groups of combinations according to a couple of conditions. This may be easiest explained with an example. Let's say I have `N = 19` people.

`List<Person> people = new List<Person>(){A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S};`

I am given as input a `PreferredGroupSize`. In this case, `PreferredGroupSize = 5;`.

I need as output combinations grouped by this `PreferredGroupSize` and +/-1 for remaining members `lastGroupSizes`.
For 19, I need all combinations of `people` with 3 groups of size 5 and a single group of size 4.

Using some modulus operations, I have already calculated the number of groups I need `numGroups`, as well as how many `numNormalSizeGroups` (i.e., number of `PreferredGroupSize` groups) and how many `numOddSizeGroups`.

This is calculated as follows:

```
//if(mod > (PreferredGroupSize)/2.0f)) make small groups.
//else make large groups.

float val1 = N % PreferredGroupSize;
float val2 = PreferredGroupSize / 2.0f;
if (N % PreferredGroupSize == 0)
{
   lastGroupSizes = PreferredGroupSize;
   numOddSizeGroups = 0;
   numNormalSizeGroups = N / PreferredGroupSize;
}
else if (val1 > val2)
{
   lastGroupSizes = PreferredGroupSize - 1;
   numOddSizeGroups = PreferredGroupSize - N % PreferredGroupSize;
   numGroups = (int)MathF.Ceiling(((float)N) / PreferredGroupSize);
   numNormalSizeGroups = numGroups - numOddSizeGroups;
}
else
{
   lastGroupSizes = PreferredGroupSize + 1;
   numOddSizeGroups = N % PreferredGroupSize;
   numGroups = (int)MathF.Floor(N / PreferredGroupSize);
   numNormalSizeGroups = numGroups - numOddSizeGroups;
}
```

The issue I'm having is I do not know how to combine the groups to form valid combinations. Valid combinations should contain no duplicate members, the number of groups should be `numGroups`, and the total members should be `N`.

These will later be added to something like a `Dictionary<List<Person>, float> Groups`

So, for example, this would be a valid combination:

```
[A B C D E], 0.55
[F G H I J], 0.72
[K L M N O], 0.74
[P Q R S], 0.75
```

Each row is a `List<Person>`, followed by a `float Score` that represents the compatibility of the group. Higher is better. The floats aren't so important. What is important is that only valid combinations should be created.

This would be an invalid combination due to a repeated member:

```
[A B C D E], 0.55
[F B H I J], 0.77
[K L M N O], 0.74
[P Q R S], 0.75
```

This would be an invalid combination due to the wrong total number of people in the groups:

```
[A B C D], 0.63
[F G H I J], 0.72
[K L M N O], 0.74
[P Q R S], 0.75
```

If either condition is violated, it should be not be added to the list of valid groups.

Right now, I do the following:

1. Produce all combinations of `people` of size `PreferredGroupSize`. `nCr = 19 choose 5`
2. Produce all combinations of `people` of size `lastGroupSizes`. `nCr = 19 choose 4`
3. Calculate a group `Score` for all combinations produced by 1 and 2 and add the combinations and `Score` to the `Groups` Dictionary.
4. Produce all combinations of `Groups` of size `numGroups`.

   This is where the major complexity comes into play, and why I want to avoid producing invalid groups:

   `nCr = ((19 choose 5) + (19 choose 4)) choose numGroups`
5. Iterate over those using a `foreach` loop, looking for valid groups, adding only valid groups to a `List<Person> ValidGroups`.
6. Break out of the loop after a given `M` groups have been calculated. I have sorted `Groups` by the `Score` so that higher scoring groups are more likely to be found first.
7. Process the valid groups.

I skip Step 1 if `numNormalSizeGroups` is 0, and I skip Step 2 if `numOddSizeGroups` is 0.

There are a ton of invalid groups created this way, and the nCr is very large.
I believe there should be a better way to do this, but I have not yet found a way. Perhaps sharing how combinations are created may be helpful in assisting:

```
        //make combinations of a certain length
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, int count)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (count == 1)
                    yield return new T[] { item };
                else
                {
                    foreach (var result in GetCombinations(items.Skip(i + 1), count - 1))
                        yield return new T[] { item }.Concat(result);
                }

                ++i;
            }
        }
```

I attribute this code to here: [Unique combinations of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249051/unique-combinations-of-list)

At the source, the code is listed as creating permutations instead of combinations. I have run this on many lists, and it produces combinations.

I'll also run through a somewhat minimal version of the current algorithm a bit with code:

```
//1. Produce all combinations of people of size PreferredGroupSize.
//2. Produce all combinations of people of size lastGroupSizes.
//Skip Step 1 if numNormalSizeGroups is 0
//Skip Step 2 if numOddSizeGroups is 0
bool calculatedNormal = false;
bool calculatedOdd = false;
while(!calculatedNormal || !calculatedOdd)
{
   int gSize = 0;
   if(!calculatedNormal)
   {
      calculatedNormal = true;
      if(numNormalSizeGroups>0)
         gSize = PreferredGroupSize;
      else
         continue;
   }
   else if(!calculatedOdd)
   {
      calculatedOdd = true;
      if(numOddSizeGroups>0)
         gSize = lastGroupSizes;
      else
         break;
   }

   //Calculate a group Score for all combinations produced by 1 and 2.
   //Add the combinations and Score to the Groups Dictionary.
   var combos = GetCombinations(people, gSize);
   float groupScore = 0;
   List<Person> curGroup;

   //for purposes of this example, generate pseudorandom float:
   Random rand = new Random();

   foreach(var combo in combos)
   {
        //groupScore = CalculateGroupScore(combo);
        groupScore = (float)rand.NextDouble();

        curGroup = new List<Person>();
        foreach(Person person in combo)
            curGroup.Add(person);
        Groups.Add(curGroup, groupScore);
   }
}

//I have sorted Groups by the Score
//so that higher scoring groups are more 
//likely to be found first.
Groups = Groups.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

//4. Produce all combinations of Groups of size numGroups.
var AllGroupCombos = GetCombinations(Groups, numGroups);

int M = 10000;
List<Person> gList = new List<Person>();
List<Person> ValidGroups = new List<Person>();
int curPeopleInGroup = 0;
bool addGroup = true;


//5. Iterate over those using a foreach loop
foreach(var combo in AllGroupCombos)
{
    curPeopleInGroup = 0;
    addGroup = true;
    gList.Clear();

    //Look for valid groups
    foreach(KeyValuePair<List<Person>, float> keyValuePair in combo)
    {
        foreach(Person person in keyValuePair.Key)
        {
            if(!gList.Contains(person)
            {
               gList.Add(person);
               ++curPeopleInGroup;
            }
            else
            {
               addGroup = false;
               break;
            }
        }
        if(!addGroup)
            break;
    }
    //Add only valid groups to a List<Person> ValidGroups.
    if(!addGroup || curPeopleInGroup != N)
        continue;
    var comboList = combo.ToList();
    ValidGroups.Add(comboList);
    
    //6. Break out of the loop after a given M 
    //groups have been calculated. 
    if(ValidGroups.Count() >= M)
       break;
}
```

I hope this was helpful, and that someone will be able to assist. :)

Comment: Do you need to produce **all** valid groupings or only the first valid grouping? Also, you say +/- 1 member for the groups of odd size. If N = 7 and R = 3 does that produce a grouping (3, 3, 1) or (3, 2, 2)?

Comment: All valid groupings. 
And, N = 7 is a bit small, but generally speaking, it would produce (3, 2, 2).
Basically, these are groups of people. I don't want people to be alone. :)

Comment: `Using some modulus operations, I have already calculated the number of groups I need NumberOfGroups, as well as how many are NormalGroupSize (i.e., number of PreferredGroupSize groups) and how many are of OddGroupSize.` - can you show this code?

Comment: Why does it have to be LINQ?

Comment: @Jamiec It's a little bit long. Do you think adding it will help answer the question? I didn't think it was important and would just take up space.

Comment: It will absolutely help you get an answer, dont make someone do the work you have already done before they can get to answering your question.

Comment: @Dialecticus I suppose it doesn't have to be LINQ, but changing that would probably require me to make more changes around the processing. I would prefer simple solutions that work with my existing code, as exmplified by the GetCombinations function, but any assistance is welcome. :)

Comment: @Jamiec I didn't think I was asking anyone to do that work. I did not think that part of the work was required in answering the question. But, sure, I'll provide it.

Comment: Basically what we ideally want is a [mcve] demonstrating exactly the problem you're having.

Comment: @Jamiec I have added the code to calculate group sizes.

Comment: @Jamiec I have now also attempted to minimally reproduce the algorithm I described.

Comment: You can't have a `Dictionary<List<Person>, float>` as `List<Person>` is not a valid key for a dictionary.

Comment: @Enigmativity I do have those, though.

Comment: @Max.D.Kaos - You're using it as a data structure, but not as a dictionary where you can access the elements as `Groups[key]`. If you're just using it as a structure then I'd argue that an anonymous type would be better than a dictionary.

Comment: @Enigmativity Indeed I am. But, this question wasn't really about dictionaries. :D Even in the question, I mentioned *something like a* Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you iterate over permutations of group assignments. Here are the steps that could solve your problem:

1. Create a list of the same length as people but with group index assigned to each person. Start with the "initial" order - repeat each index as many times as members in the given group, taking into account some groups will be smaller. In your case you will have 5 zeros, 5 ones, 5 twos and 4 threes: `{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3}`.
2. There is a unique valid group assignment associated to each permutation of the index list above - assign each person to the group index in the given position
3. Iterate over all permutations of the list from point 1. You will have to implement something like `next_permutation` in c++. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390954/how-would-you-calculate-all-possible-permutations-of-0-through-n-iteratively/12768718#12768718) is an example implementation from another SoF user, in another question.

Doing these steps you will be able to iterate over all valid combinations.