# permutations of k objects from a set of n algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

I'm looking for an efficient way to achieve this:

1. you have a set of numbers, let's say that our set is equal to 4 (N = 4);
2. you have to generate all permutations of 3 elements (K = 3);

Output for N = 4 and K = 3:

```
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 3 2
1 3 4
1 4 2
1 4 3
2 1 3
2 1 4
2 3 1
2 3 4
2 4 1
2 4 3
3 1 2
3 1 4
3 2 1
3 2 4
3 4 1
3 4 2
4 1 2
4 1 3
4 2 1
4 2 3
4 3 1
4 3 2
```

Anyone have a great, nice'n'quick algorithm up their sleeve or web reference??

Thanks!

Comment: This question has been answered a hundred times. Please search on your topic before posting. Flagged.

Comment: @TylerDurden the general way of doing this is to vote for close as exact duplicate.

Comment: @TylerDurden: There are familiar topics you are right, I've already checked them, but with this difference that you have permutations of N elements (N=K) not permutations of k objects from a set of n elements.

Comment: You can't go better than O(n!/(n-k)!) complexity since this is the number of the permutations.

Comment: @icepack: Then I should change the concept of the algorithm! :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to generate all possible permutations of a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710713/algorithm-to-generate-all-possible-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this pseudocode:

```
permute(set, output, len)  //output will hold all the permutations

for each number in the set do
    choose number and store it at output[0]
    if(!empty(set))
        call permute(set{without the number}, output + (len - 1)!, len-1) //adjust the position
```

Invoke by `permute(set, output, k)`

Comment: @Woot4Moo you're always welcomed to criticize as long as it constructive

Comment: i should have been more clear in my statement, it was hard to deduce if the original `output+1` was referring to the index of output or if it was meant to increment whatever the previous value was by 1