# How to make group of unique item of n element in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, grouping

I have a list of int in c#, I want to group them in unique elements.

```
List<int> items = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 1, 2 };
```

As you can see it's have 4 element 1,3,1,2. I want to group them in size of 2. for example

```
[1,3],[1,2]
[1,1],[3,2]
```

As you can see, it's make these unique group. I am not sure how to achieve this in C#. In this case I need to group by 2, but maybe I need to group by any other number (N).

The list may contains more item than 4.

Comment: You want combinations without repetitions?

Comment: What about `[2,3]`?

Comment: @DavidG if you group [2,3] only [1,1] will remain. it doesn't matter which come first in group so [2,3] will be same as [3,2]

Comment: @Tim yes, but it 2 groups will be same if element are same and just index are different.

Comment: Did you try searching for an answer then? There's lots of examples on Stack Overflow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132758/words-combinations-without-repetition

Comment: *I am not sure how to achieve this in C#*. Do you know how to do it in a language agnostic way? If you dont, then first figure that out, then try to write some code and then come here asking for help on specific problems you might be encountering.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for useful link, I am checking.

Comment: @Adrian: read [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26050/Permutations-Combinations-and-Variations-using-C-G), tt's interesting. Then you can use the class `Facet.Combinatorics.Combination` to get all combinations without repetitions. You can use `Distinct` with a custom `IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>>`:  `var combinations = new Facet.Combinatorics.Combinations<int>(items, 2).Distinct(new SequenceIgnoreOrderComparer<int>());`. `Equals` of the comparer: `return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x.OrderBy(t => t), y.OrderBy(t => t));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks, I am checking

Answer (score 0):

Just try this out, i have loaded the result to list.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6};
            List<int[]> numArrays = new List<int[]>();

            var numArray = numbers.ToArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = i ; j < numArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    int[] nums = new int[2];
                    nums[0] = numArray[i];
                    nums[1] = numArray[j];
                    numArrays.Add(nums);
                }
            }
```

Comment: when you have 6 item in list, the subarray will be 3 in a single T (of 2 elements per item), please check.